# jquery tab redirect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).show(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });

});






<div class="container">

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">File Encryption</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">File Integrity</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="tab_container">

        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
       </div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
       </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

this was index.php page. Now I want to get redirected from another page called, test.php but I want it to have tab2 open when I get back to index.php. how would I accomplist that.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [jquery-ui documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected):

Zero-based index of the tab to be selected on initialization. To set all tabs to unselected pass -1 as value.

Code examples

Initialize a tabs with the selected option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ selected: 3 });
Get or set the selected option, after init.
//getter
var selected = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "selected" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "selected", 3 );
```